# Question on HDMI and DisplayPort Compatibility

Tags: computer-hardware

I have a very simple question: If a PC has a DisplayPort output, can I plug in my monitor which supports HDMI?

Comment: downvoted your question because a simple search answers it ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=dp+to+hdmi&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 0):

There are adapters from DisplayPort to HDMI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I then need an active or passive adapter? And does such an adapter really work in my case? I thought it only works if the output of the PC were HDMI and the monitor cable would be Displayport.

Comment: Did you google this at all before asking here? It's kind of everywhere about whether Displayport supports HDMI and what you need to connect them together.

Comment: @DKNguyen I was surprised about the answer because of what it says [here](https://www.exhibitedge.com/how-to-connect-a-displayport-device-to-a-hdmi-monitor/): *If the DisplayPort output is a Dual mode DisplayPort then it has the ability to recognize and adjust the signal to HDMI when a passive adapter cable is connected. I mentioned this in an earlier video and said that I got lucky. I bought a passive adapter cable and it worked. Sometimes it will and sometimes it won’t. If the DisplayPort graphics card is only a single mode DisplayPort then you must use an active adapter or converter.*

Comment: @Hermi What did you find surprising about it? Even DVI had VGA built into in the sense that VGA was always there for some pins in the DVI connector and you just needed a passive adapter to reroute those signals to your VGA adapter. DVI was serial but VGA was parallel so you couldn't just swap modes. IT was easier to just to make the VGA always present. But DisplayPort and HDMI is serial so you instead you can make it change modes if it needs to.

Comment: @DKNguyen So you are saying that I can (safely) buy a passive adapter) The same site that I referenced in my last comment states that I need to make sure that the output port of the PC is DP++, but I didn't find this information for the PC I'm considering...

Comment: @Hermi I would just try a passive adapter. Active adapers are so much more expensive that it's probably worth the gamble. And the odds are in your favour if your PC is newer. You need to look at your PC motherboard or video card, depending on where you are getting the video from.

Comment: @DKNguyen The PC doesn't have an AMD or NVIDIA graphics card, so I think the Displayport output should come from the motherboard. Let's say we're taking a specific PC, e.g. HP EliteDesk 800 G2, where I can find its motherboard specs? I didn't find it on the website of HP. Thanks!